# Why not show my results when i use not squeal with and

Tags: sql

Why not show my results when i use not squeal with and in this case

```
SELECT 
'999' as A,
'999' AS B,
'000' AS C,
'000' as D
WHERE
A <> '999'
and B <> '999'
and C <> '999'
AND D <> '999'
```

This terminal results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1E7U.jpg)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: This is not a valid SQL query, you would need a derived table.

Comment: @Pylon  teradata

Comment: `where` executed before `select`, hence it never knows your literal values

Answer (score 1):

May be because you have set the values for A,B,C,D and sql processor does not see any ones.
And you use '`AND`' - so it means that the condition should be resolved only together, for all values. So that is why you don`t see C and D.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement a *derived table* such as:

```
select A, B, C, D
from (
    select 
    '999' as A,
    '999' as B,
    '000' as C,
    '000' as D
)t
where
A <> '999'
and B <> '999'
and C <> '999'
and D <> '999';
```

Comment: Thank but the result set is empty, and i just want know why results not show in Where condition. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but why would it *not* be empty - the row does not satisfy the criteria clearly eg A = '999' and the criteria says A <> '999' - using *and* means that all 4 predicates must be true.

Comment: Nice you got it, I don’t why in the criteria , You can try to execute your sql query on https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/ for prove. That’s empty. And I have no idea why. 

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we can't use WHERE clause to filter the column that dynamically evaluates. Try to use HAVING instead.

```
SELECT 
'999' as A,
'999' AS B,
'000' AS C,
'000' as D
HAVING
A <> '999'
and B <> '999'
and C <> '999'
AND D <> '999'
```